# Figuring a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

I have a differential equation that goes like this:

$$0.005*\frac{diL}{dt}+iL*2=(0.01-iL)*1$$

And i'm trying to figure out the iL from the equation. I decided to first get rid of the coefficients, and got $$ 0.005*\frac{diL}{dt}+iL*2=(0.01-iL)*1 => 0.005*\frac{diL}{dt}+iL*2=0.01-iL$$
$$\frac{diL}{dt}+iL*2=2-\frac{iL}{0.005} $$
$$ \frac{diL}{dt}+iL=1-100iL$$

From here on, I tried to calculate iL and I ended up with the answer as $$ iL = \frac{1}{100}+\frac{C}{exp(100*t)}$$
And by calculating C, we get $$iL = \frac{1}{100}-\frac{1}{100}*exp(-100*t) $$

I arranged the calculation so that I only had 1 at the right side, as such:
$$ \frac{diL}{dt}+100*iL=1 $$
But my calculations seem wrong. Have I done some mistakes along the way, or am I completely off?
Value for L is 0.005, if that makes a difference (I dont think it should(?)).
The original differential equation is 
$$L*\frac{diL}{dt}+iL*R1=(Iin-iL)*Rs$$
where I have already input the values for all except iL.

Comment: Is this an equation for a circuit with a resistor and an inductor? Then the original equation is wrong

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/cae49301987869996088333cc298fada.png This is the original circuit, and I have been confirmed that at least the differential equation is correct

Comment: Then it should be $\frac{di_L}{dt}$, not $\frac{dL}{dt}$. $i_L$ is the current through the inductor.

Comment: @Andrei That is correct, made an edit.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when you went from the second line to the third. You did not divide the $i_L$ term on the left by $0.005$. I would move that therm to the right, even before I do the division: $$L\frac{di_L}{dt}=I_{in}R_S-i_L(R_s+R_1)$$

Comment: This seems to give me either $$iL = \frac{1}{300}-\frac{1}{300}*exp(-300*t)$$ or $$iL = \frac{1}{300}-\frac{1}{300}*exp(-600*t)$$, but they both seem to be incorrect.